# How to save a figure with multiple sub floats to a single pdf file

Tags: floats, pdf

How to save a figure with multiple sub floats to a single pdf file.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{pic.png}
\put(50,26){\textbf{A}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{pic.png}
\put(50,26){\textbf{B}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{pic.png}
\put(50,26){\textbf{C}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{pic.png}
\put(50,26){\textbf{D}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline test & test \\ 
\hline  &  \\ 
\hline 
\end{tabular} 
\caption{\label{fig-p1} caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

This is what it produces:

[image]

I want to save the figure in the red square into a single pdf file (without white margins) e.g. fig1.pdf. Then next time, I can only include fig1.pdf instead of so many sub floats:

```
\begin{figure}\centering
\includegraphics{fig1.pdf}
\caption{\label{fig-p1} caption.}
\end{figure}
```

I ask this because many journals ask you to submit figures separately from the main text.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Here to download the text files: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45318932/test.zip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might like the [`standalone`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/standalone) class for this:

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage[percent]{overpic}
\begin{document}

\centering
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \put(50,26){\textbf{A}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \put(50,26){\textbf{B}}
\end{overpic}\\
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-c}
    \put(50,26){\textbf{C}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{overpic}[width=0.49\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \put(50,26){\textbf{D}}
\end{overpic}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
    \hline test & test \\
    \hline      &      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```